# How is the hardware TX queue selected by default?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, performance, socket

NICs may have multiple hardware RX and TX queues, and there are [several methods](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/scaling.html) which allow choosing which RX and TX queues are used for a given flow/packet, though most are focused on the RX side.

What I can't find, however, is the behavior if none of this is enabled. E.g., if XPS (Transmit Packet Steering) is not enabled, how is the TX queue chosen.

Empirically, on an is4gen EC2 instance with 16 CPUs and 16 combined RX-TX queues, it seems as if a random TX queue is selected for the life of a flow: i.e., even if a second `iperf` test is done with the same source and destination addresses, the TX queue chosen to handle the flow changes.